# Unable to import from @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons when using an alias

Tags: angular, font-awesome, font-awesome-5, angular-fontawesome

I'm unable to import icons when I use an alias to reference them. I noticed the problem specifically with from `@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons`. You sometimes need to use an alias because there might be a duplicate name for an icon in libraries and you want to import them both.

This is code that was working prior to a small Angular upgrade (7.1 -> 7.2).
Here's the guidance from the [fontawesome documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/setup/importing-icons). See the last section on the page.

I've tried upgrading fortawesome packages and screwing around with the aliases and icons being imported. I noticed that removing the alias allowed me to import the icons just fine.

**app module**

```
import { library, dom } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

import { faSpinner, faCopy } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
library.add(faSpinner, faCopy);

import { faCopy as farCopy } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
library.add(farCopy); // <-- This is where the error is thrown

dom.watch();
```

**relevant packages**

```
"@angular/common": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/forms": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "^0.2.21",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.21",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.10.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.1",
```

**Browser Error**
`Uncaught ReferenceError: farCopy is not defined`

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: picture link was broken, added the raw text from the console.

Comment: Do you get this error with any other icon? Plus, can you show the full error?

Comment: yeah any icon i aliased. never resolved, worked around though. might abandon and switch to angular material icons if it's ever a sticking point in the future :/

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue today, but I'm using Typescript instead of Angular, unsure if this solution will work for you too.

My issue was when adding to fontawesome-svg-core from free-regular-svg-icons, I would get a compile error in my typescript.

```
Argument of type 'IconDefinition' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IconDefinitionOrPack'.
```

when I did

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faClock} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
library.add(faClock); // <-- error here
```

What worked for me was forcing faClock to not be evaluated by

```
library.add(faClock as any);
```

Comment if that does or doesn't work for you, I'll take this post down if this solution doesn't translate over for you.

Comment: that's specifically what does NOT work for me. If I add the alias "as something" it will not import. Unfortunately you HAVE to add the alias to use the same named icon in multiple packs.